# FireBird 2.5 можно ли создать в одном запросе создание нескольких таблиц?

Tags: firebird

Можно ли создать в одном запросе сразу несколько таблиц? Ругается на второй `Create`. Не знаю какой разделитель (если такой существует вообще), в документации не нашёл ничего. Хочу объединить эти команды в одну если есть возможность. [image: Пример команд]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В одном запросе может быть только одна команда DSQL.

Но есть специальная команда EXECUTE BLOCK, внутри которой можно выполнить несколько команд PSQL.

Но create table - это команда DSQL, ее нельзя выполнять внутри блока PSQL.

Но внутри PSQL можно выполнять EXECUTE STATEMENT, внутри которого можно выполнять команды DSQL

Итого можно сделать следующий запрос:

```
EXECUTE BLOCK
AS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE STATEMENT 'CREATE TABLE1 ...';
  EXECUTE STATEMENT 'CREATE TABLE2 ...';
  ...
END
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!